# Looping different images in different cells of a table with different times

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a table with 4 rows and 7 columns. In each td I have placed a link (a) with three random images (created by php with no problem :)). The idea is to fadeIn and FadeOut the three images infinitely in each td. Furthermore, the time of looping must be different between the cells. Tha images should change at different times, not all of them at the same time.
I think that I can achieve that goal with JQuery, but I've been looking for it in the net with no result. I can find solutions when there is only one loop, but how can you dou it when you have so many different loops at the same time?

HTML:

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td><a href="#" class="casella"><img src="" /><img src="" /><img src="" /></a></td>
    <td><a href="#" class="casella"><img src="" /><img src="" /><img src="" /></a></td>
    ...till 7 columns
</tr>
<tr... till 4 rows
</tbody>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
a.casella {position:relative;} 
a.casella img{position: absolute; left:0; top:0; display:none; z-index:-1; width:120px; height:120px}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it!!!
I just inserted this code AFTER the table.

```
var min=3000;
            var max=8000;
            var transMult=0.4;
            var currIdx = new Array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
            var i=0;
            function animateBG(i) {
                    currIdx[i]=(currIdx[i] < 2) ? currIdx[i] +1 : 0;
                    displayTime=Math.random()*(max-min)+min;
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        transitionTime=Math.floor(displayTime*transMult);
                        $("td a").eq(i).children("img").css('z-index',1);
                        $("td a").eq(i).children("img").eq(currIdx[i]).css('z-index', 2).fadeIn(transitionTime, function() {
                        $("td a").eq(i).children("img").not(this).hide();
                        animateBG(i);
                        });
                    }, displayTime)
            }
            $(window).load(function()
                {
                    for(j=0;j<24;j++)
                    {
                        animateBG(j);
                    }
               });
```